# How can i keep opacity=1 5 more seconds after realeasing the hover on another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So i have a map, and on hover on certain point, the address will appear. But i would prefer to keep the opacity for 5 more seconds so that the user could copy the text in that bubble. I have an example of what i have right now [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wLsa4/1/). And i would preffer to do this using only javascript if it's possible.

```
#harta {
width:958px;
height:465px;
background:url(https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/attachment/u/0/?ui=2&ik=9315d35c80&view=att&th=13c903efbb6093fa&attid=0.1&disp=inline&realattid=f_hclsb8jy0&safe=1&zw&saduie=AG9B_P9aYbjGhKjTXzh9nfNdKFkW&sadet=1359636669888&sads=BF04ljTz2X-4v_L8ApM49KM_Bgo);
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
}

.town {
position:absolute;
width:25px;
height:30px;
display:block;
cursor:pointer;
}

#point1 {
top:85px;
left:435px;
}

#point2 {
top:107px;
left:415px;
}

#point3 {
top:117px;
left:387px;
}

#point4 {
top:137px;
left:410px;
}

#point5 {
top:212px;
left:491px;
}

#point6 {
top:432px;
left:490px;
}

.info {
background:white;
position:absolute;
border-radius:5px;
padding:10px;
opacity:0;
display:inline-block;
min-width:250px;
}

#point1:hover+ #info_point1 {
top:55px;
left:460px;
opacity:1;
}

#point2:hover+ #info_point2 {
top:77px;
left:440px;
opacity:1;
}

#point3:hover+ #info_point3 {
top:87px;
left:412px;
opacity:1;
}

#point4:hover+ #info_point4 {
top:107px;
left:435px;
opacity:1;
}

#point5:hover+ #info_point5 {
top:182px;
left:516px;
opacity:1;
}

#point6:hover+ #info_point6 {
top:402px;
left:515px;
opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: I suggest considering the `hoverIntent` plugin, which supports the feature: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way of obtaining that is to add to the hover a transition delay:

```
#point1:hover + info{transition:all 0s 5s;-webkit-transition:all 0s 5s;-o-transition:all 0s 5s;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little trick. I could not find how to run a function for 5 seconds, so I changed the functionality which Is to be reverted after 5 seconds.

```
$("#point1").on("mouseleave", function(){
    $("#point1").css("opacity", "1");
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("called");
        $("#point1").css("opacity", "0.3");
    }, 5000);
});
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upPbA/1/)